# like facebook fan page error in android

Tags: android, facebook

i want user to like me facebook fan page from my android app,
how to do that 
below is my code

318093631634608 is the any page;
list of PERMISSIONS

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays
            .asList("page_fan","publish_actions" ,"user_likes","friends_likes","manage_pages","publish_stream","user_status", "user_online_presence", "friends_online_presence");

private void likePage()
{
     Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
     if (session != null)
     {
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                        .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                return;
            }

    Request likeRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "318093631634608" + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() 
    {           
         @Override
         public void onCompleted(Response response) 
        {
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {
                Toast.makeText(Facebook.this,
                        error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                Log.i("error like", error.getErrorMessage().toString());
            } else {
                Log.i("user id", "success page liked");
                Toast.makeText(Facebook.this, "success loked the page",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    Request.executeBatchAsync(likeRequest);
    }
}
```

logcat

```
12-03 22:31:04.512: W/com.facebook.Session(16294): Should not pass a read permission (page_fan) to a request for publish or manage authorization
12-03 22:31:04.519: W/com.facebook.Session(16294): Should not pass a read permission (user_likes) to a request for publish or manage authorization
12-03 22:31:04.519: W/com.facebook.Session(16294): Should not pass a read permission (friends_likes) to a request for publish or manage authorization
12-03 22:31:04.519: W/com.facebook.Session(16294): Should not pass a read permission (user_status) to a request for publish or manage authorization
12-03 22:31:04.519: W/com.facebook.Session(16294): Should not pass a read permission (user_online_presence) to a request for publish or manage authorization
12-03 22:31:04.519: W/com.facebook.Session(16294): Should not pass a read permission (friends_online_presence) to a request for publish or manage authorization
```

and some time it shows 
App does not have permission to make this call in android

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to like a page programmatically, only comments and posts. but to like a post on facebook, I use this part of code to create the request.

```
Request likeRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), pageid + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
    @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {

        }
});
```

Hope this help..

Comment: it shows App does not have permission to make this call in android

Comment: Though u add any permission API doesn't allow you for doing this.. Instead u can open a webview with page URL..

Comment: previously i am doning that by nevigating to page  url, know i want to change that to like on button click

Comment: i think facebook api sholud provide this feature to us, since they are keeping track of each n every thing of a particular user,if the user likes the particular page it will be only once, becz after that the user will b associate with that object, it will no longer available for him to like again..